# Adding a value for Enum Column for Mysql - will it involve a downtime?

Tags: mysql, enums, alter-table, rds, downtime

I want to update an Enum in RDS Mysql and add a value to an column. I have huge data existing in the same table which I want to update. I assume that while updating the schema of the table, the table gets locked which clearly involves a downtime during which my service will go down. My MysqlServer version is 5.5.40.

But as I am adding a value to the Enum, is the RDS Mysql server smart enough to detect that it doesn't need to scan existing rows and update the schema quickly in the time of executing a simple query without scanning values of all existing rows of the Enum column?

Answer (score 5):

On Mysql 5.5.46, I added a new ENUM value to an existing list:

```
enum ('a','b','c','d')
```

to

```
enum ('a','b','c','d','e')
```

ALTER TABLE CHANGE [column] took less than 1 second for 500k rows.

This seems to be the bug : https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45567 and it seems to be fixed in 5.1.40, 5.5.0 and 6.0.14

On Mysql 5.6.33, I tried

```
enum ('a','b','c','d')
```

to

```
enum ('a','b','c','e','d')
```

and ALTER TABLE CHANGE [column] did not update the existing d's to e's as described here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11484/is-it-possible-to-change-enum-lists/11485#11485

I cannot find the version where this bug was fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Bad news, you seem to not be in luck.

http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/

[Article mirror](https://www.91ni.net/pw3sr/1ireg1.html)

> The problem is that changing the member list for an ENUM column
>   restructures the entire table with ALTER TABLE, which can be very
>   expensive on resources and time. If you have ENUM('red', 'blue',
>   'black') but need to change it to ENUM('red', 'blue', 'white'), MySQL
>   needs to rebuild your table and look through every record to check for
>   the now-invalid value 'black'. MySQL is literally dumb and will even
>   do this when all you did was add a new value to the end of the member
>   list! (It is rumored that appending an ENUM member list will be
>   handled better in the future, but I doubt that this is a high priority
>   feature.)

Comment: The link is very old. Through some of the other sources, I got the idea that it was a bug which may have got fixed in 5.5.* versions.

Comment: How will I know the downtime through the unit test?

Comment: I don't mean unit test as in like JUnit. But as in a dev data base like you have Unit Test, UAT, Production. So have a significantly large db in a play sandbox, do what you were planning to do, and stare at your wristwatch :)